# Replace XML node element with a variable

Tags: sql-server, xml, sql-server-2008, xquery

I currently have the following code creating XML under parent nodes named PARTY. Inside the PARTY nodes is another node called ROLE. My question is how can I replace the current ROLE node which just says ROLE with my [SequenceNr] variable inside the xquery.

I had attempted doing a replace in the @OutputXml but that didn't work, and I think there should be an easy way in the xquery that I do not know about.

Current code:

```
WITH [PartyNodes] AS
        (
            SELECT  (   
                        SELECT  [dbo].[XmlA](@Id),
                                [dbo].[XmlB](@Id)
                        FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE
                    ) AS [AllTogether]
        )
        ,[NumberedSequences] AS
        (
            SELECT  'PARTY' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) + 10) + '_ROLE1' AS [PartySequenceNr], -- party label
                    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) + 10 AS [SequenceNr], -- party sequence
                    [T].[Party].[query]('.') AS [TheNode]
            FROM [PartyNodes]
            CROSS APPLY [AllTogether].[nodes]('/PARTY') AS T(Party)
        )
        SELECT @OutputXml = (   SELECT [TheNode].[query]('let $p:=/PARTY[1]
                                                      let $lbl:=sql:column("PartySequenceNr")
                                                      let $nr:=sql:column("SequenceNr")
                                                      return
                                                     <PARTY SequenceNumber="{$nr}" xlink_label="{$lbl}" >
                                                     {$p/*}
                                                    </PARTY>'
                                                )
                                FROM [NumberedSequences]
                                FOR XML PATH(''),ROOT('PARTIES')
                                );
```

Current output:

```
<PARTY SequenceNumber="1" xlink:label="PARTY1_ROLE1">
    <INDIVIDUAL>
      <NAME>
         <FullName>Test</FullName>
       </NAME>
    </INDIVIDUAL>
    <ROLES>
       <ROLE>
            <A>Test</A>
       </ROLE>
    </ROLES>
</PARTY>
```

Desired output:

```
<PARTY SequenceNumber="1" xlink:label="PARTY1_ROLE1">
    <INDIVIDUAL>
      <NAME>
         <FullName>Test</FullName>
       </NAME>
    </INDIVIDUAL>
    <ROLES>
       <ROLE SequenceNumber="1" xlink:label="PARTY1_ROLE1">>
            <A>Test</A>
       </ROLE>
    </ROLES>
</PARTY>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried to follow your thoughts, but couldn't...

There are two functions `XmlA` and `XmlB`. First you combine their results into `AllTogether`. Later you use `.nodes('/PARTY')` to read from this, but the XML you show has got just one single `PARTY` node as root.

Further more you use `FLWOR-XQuery` to *insert* your two attributes. But I doubt, that `xlink_label` would ever show up as `xlink:label`.

The XML you show cannot be the result of the above... Or I'm missing something...

My first thought is: This seems to be over complicated... If the following does not help, please provide more details about your goal, try to [set up a `MCVE`](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). This might be [the XY-problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

I start with the XML without attributes, assuming this is the result of the fore going:

```
DECLARE @xml XML=
N'<PARTY>
    <INDIVIDUAL>
      <NAME>
         <FullName>Test</FullName>
       </NAME>
    </INDIVIDUAL>
    <ROLES>
       <ROLE>
            <A>Test</A>
       </ROLE>
    </ROLES>
</PARTY>';
```

--This query will insert the attributes in `PARTY` and in `ROLE`

```
DECLARE @PartySequenceNr INT = 1;
DECLARE @SequenceNr VARCHAR(100)='PARTY1_ROLE1';

SELECT @xml.query
(N' 
    let $p:=/PARTY[1]
    let $lbl:=sql:variable("@PartySequenceNr")
    let $nr:=sql:variable("@SequenceNr")
    return
    <PARTY SequenceNumber="{$nr}" xlink_label="{$lbl}" >
    {
        for $nd in $p/*
        return
            if(local-name($nd)="ROLES") then
            ( 
                <ROLES><ROLE SequenceNumber="{$nr}" xlink_label="{$lbl}" >
                {$nd/ROLE/*}
                </ROLE></ROLES>
            )
            else $nd
    }
    </PARTY>
')
```

The result:

```
<PARTY SequenceNumber="PARTY1_ROLE1" xlink_label="1">
  <INDIVIDUAL>
    <NAME>
      <FullName>Test</FullName>
    </NAME>
  </INDIVIDUAL>
  <ROLES>
    <ROLE SequenceNumber="PARTY1_ROLE1" xlink_label="1">
      <A>Test</A>
    </ROLE>
  </ROLES>
</PARTY>
```

### With namespace `xlink`

Use this if you need the namespace

```
SELECT @xml.query
(N' declare namespace xlink="DummyUrl";
    let $p:=/PARTY[1]
    let $lbl:=sql:variable("@PartySequenceNr")
    let $nr:=sql:variable("@SequenceNr")
    return
    <PARTY SequenceNumber="{$nr}" xlink:label="{$lbl}" >
    {
    for $nd in $p/*
    return
        if(local-name($nd)="ROLES") then
        ( 
            <ROLES><ROLE SequenceNumber="{$nr}" xlink:label="{$lbl}" >

            {$nd/ROLE/*}

            </ROLE></ROLES>
        )
        else $nd
    }
    </PARTY>
')
```

The result

```
<PARTY SequenceNumber="PARTY1_ROLE1" xmlns:xlink="DummyUrl" xlink:label="1">
  <INDIVIDUAL>
    <NAME>
      <FullName>Test</FullName>
    </NAME>
  </INDIVIDUAL>
  <ROLES>
    <ROLE SequenceNumber="PARTY1_ROLE1" xlink:label="1">
      <A>Test</A>
    </ROLE>
  </ROLES>
</PARTY>
```

Comment: wow that's awesome. how efficient is this? or how would I test it's performance. I actually ended up doing this a different way. I created a table type, where I inserted my labels and some other information and then I am passing that variable type to my party functions and selecting the specific record from there.

Comment: @DRockClimber, you can test the performance basically with `DECLARE @d DATETIME=GETDATE(); DoSomething; SELECT CAST(GETDATE()-@d AS TIME);` But this approach is - for sure - not best performing... Creating the XML just to press it through some `FLWOR-XQuery` must be slow... Your whole thing smells over complicated, but I don't know any details. As pointed out, even the provided information is inconsistent...

Comment: Can you clarify something for me. Where are you specifying that $nd holds the value of ROLES before you check for it in the if condition?

Comment: @DRockClimber This line is responsible for the value of `$nd`: `for $nd in $p/*` This will read all sub-nodes from $p. Working down the `for`-loop will shift each sub-node into $nd, one after the other. The node *ROLES* needs a different handling, therefore the `if` checking with `local-name()`.